# Create user variable in Intellij File Template

Tags: java, intellij-idea, velocity

I am trying to use Intellij's file templates (not live templates) to help mitigate how much boilerplate code I use when making Services, daos, and their interfaces.

I am able to use all the system defined variables just fine, such as

`${PACKAGE_NAME}`

What I want though, is to be able to use my own variable names, like

`${MY_USER_INPUT}`

however, when i do this like above, I get an error

The documentation says :

> It is also possible to specify arbitrary number of custom variables in format ${<VARIABLE_NAME>}.

and then Intellij is supposed to prompt the user for the value.

However, this just plain doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I suggest you report it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug, submitted as [IDEA-63628](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-63628). Please watch/vote.

Comment: thanks, i probably should have submitted this directly to you. its good to know you are following this site as well. I still have 9 installed, so i can test it out there and wait for the bug fix.

Answer (score 0):

I use the custom variabeles in alot of template and ${MY_USER_INPUT} should work.

What error do you get ? what vesion of IntelliJ Do you use ?

In general stating "however, when i do this like above, I get an error" really isent helpfull people cannot guess whats wrong if you dont tell us, you should at least post a clear example of you file template and the exact error.

Comment: I have tried this and didn't get the result. Idea simply doesn't promt me at all. Idea 10.